# How can I cause my MessageBox to pop up on top of all forms?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, messagebox

I am currently providing information to the user with a message box in my C program, but the message box is appearing behind all other forms of my application.

How can I bring it forward so that it appears in front of all my forms, or set its parent?

Here is the code I'm currently using to show the message box:

```
MessageBox(0,error_msg, "Error - No Algorithm", MB_OK );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's appearing behind all forms now is because you've not specified an owner window. That causes it to appear directly on top of the desktop window. The problem is that your other windows are already covering up the desktop window, so they blissfully continue to cover up your message box, too.

The solution, as you suspect, is to specify one of your windows as the owner for the message box. You do that by specifying their window handle (`HWND`) as the first argument to the function:

```
MessageBox(hWnd,                    // the window handle for your owner window
           error_msg,               // the message to be displayed
           "Error - No Algorithm",  // the title
           MB_OK);                  // flags indicating contents and behavior
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505.aspx) provides additional information.

Comment: Is there anyway i can get the hwnd if i just know the form name? this is because i linked my application to other people's part and i could not get the hwnd pass to my function.

Comment: @user: I don't understand what that means. First of all, there are no "forms" in C. The Windows API has *windows*, but it doesn't have "forms". And those windows don't have names. They have window titles (or captions), but those are not required to be unique. It doesn't matter *which* window you specify as the owner, use one of the ones you own locally.

Comment: sorry, i'm quite new in C coding. Or can you please provide me some examples on how i can get the hwnd?

Comment: @user: You get the hwnd as the return value of the `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx` function. You *have* to call one of those two functions to create your window. What tutorial or book are you following to learn C? It should talk about window handles (abbreviated hwnd) in the first chapter. Edit your question (using the links at the bottom left) and post your full code if you want better help.

Comment: the front end is written in VB6.

Comment: @user: Ah, I understand now. So you're not creating a window at all in C. Then, the best thing to do is to show the message box from VB 6. Return an error code from your C library function, and then write an `if` statement in your VB 6 application to check the return code and show the appropriate error message. If you are just trying to get raw speed (presumably, you're writing an algorithm?) by writing parts of your app in C, there's no good reason to spend time learning the Windows API just to show a message box.

Comment: You're right, it's going to be extremely difficult to get the handle to a window created by a VB 6 app from your C code. You'd have to enumerate all the windows in the currently running process, check their titles, and see if they match up to the one you expect. That requires you to learn about callbacks and a bunch of other stuff that is neither pretty nor necessary to do what you want. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best. Just indicate failure from your C code and let the VB 6 front end handle it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I thought it might b simpler to do it in C as i'm also new in vb6. =)

Comment: I had change my code to MessageBox(FindWindow(TEXT("myform"),TEXT("myform")),error_msg, "Error - No Algorithm", MB_OK ); and it works. however, if i opens other forms before this line of code, it will just pop up behind again

Comment: @user: If you don't mind me asking, why are you new in both languages? VB 6 is extremely old and out of date. If you're writing a new application, there's not much point in learning VB 6 to do it. Newer languages make a lot of things much easier. And C is an extremely difficult language to learn, and the Windows API (which you'll need to program against to write GUI applications in C) is a confusing beast and very difficult to try to pick up as you go along.

Comment: Might I suggest using VB.NET instead? You can download the Express version for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Basic). It's very unlikely that you will need the raw speed of C if you're using one of the .NET languages. VB 6 code is notably slower, but the JIT compiler used by the .NET languages will make up for most of the speed differences.

Comment: I have change job recently and this job needs me to maintain the older softwares. Thus, I have not much choice. =)

Comment: @user: Understood. And the message box will always appear on top of the window you set as its owner. If you show another window, it's possible for it to appear on top of your message box because it can appear on top of the message box's owner window. You need to set the message box owner as the window that will be in the foreground. (I'm also surprised the `FindWindow` function works as shown. I didn't think VB 6 used the name of the form as the name of the *class*, but I've never done any significant degree of VB 6 and C interop. Life is too short.)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the HWND to parent to. `0` or `NULL` means "no parent", so the resulting message box will not be modal. You need to supply the parent HWND to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Hi paulcam, thanks. May I know how I can get the HWND from my C codes? Can you provide me some guidance or example on how to get the current HWND?

Comment: It actually means no *owner*. There is a difference between a "parent" window and an "owner" window. Raymond Chen explains the difference [in this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx).

Comment: @user: You should have a variable you use to keep track of the window handle. It's the value returned by the `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx` function. The boilerplate code in Visual Studio creates one called `hWnd` by default, which is a good name.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this but just search for the window by class or title using `FindWindow` and supply that `HWND` as the first parameter to `MessageBox`.